# Failed to load page. Unsupported URL

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone

I have a link on my web page that links the user to a certain application in App Store. But when the user clicks on that link, the browser throws an error saying "Failed to load page. Unsupported URL" I have tested this on various iOS device and this problem is observed on iOS devices that came out before iPhone 7. Here is the link to the application : https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/bounce-mobile/id1346771528 I am not able to find out what's causing this and how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated! 
Thanks
[image: Error]

Comment: would be nice to see the code... the URL.. if it is a secure url or not... etc etc etc

Comment: @GIJOW https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/bounce-mobile/id1346771528

Comment: What versions of iOS are those devices running?  That typically has more to do with the behavior of Safari.  Also, Can you post the `<a href=` code from your web page?   Also, you have not disabled App Store access on those test devices through something like MDM, have you?

Answer (score 1):

Still missing some of the details, but looking at your URL, it seems somewhat non-standard.  I would use the Apple-recommended URL format of https://itunes.apple.com/app/id1346771528

Other than that, I would make sure you do not have the App Store disabled on the devices through something like mobile device management (MDM).  Make sure you see an App Store icon on those devices and can open it.

In addition, I would plug the device into your Mac while trying to click on the link and use Safari debugging to see if you get more information - [more details here](https://appletoolbox.com/2014/05/use-web-inspector-debug-mobile-safari/).